# How to change bar chart color when using Holoview with Plotly backend?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, holoviews

I am using example in this [documentation](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/plotly/Bars.html)

This is code to plot Bar chart but change default blue color to red, using Bokeh backend.

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

data = [('one',8),('two', 10), ('three', 16), ('four', 8), ('five', 4), ('six', 1)]

bars = hv.Bars(data, hv.Dimension('Car occupants'), 'Count')
bars.opts(color="red")
bars
```

[image: bokeh red plot]

I tried similar code, only change bokeh to plotly. But the color="red" has no effect.

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('plotly')

data = [('one',8),('two', 10), ('three', 16), ('four', 8), ('five', 4), ('six', 1)]

bars = hv.Bars(data, hv.Dimension('Car occupants'), 'Count')
bars.opts(color="red")
bars
```

[image: plotly]

I also tried

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('plotly')

data = [('one',8),('two', 10), ('three', 16), ('four', 8), ('five', 4), ('six', 1)]

bars = hv.Bars(data, hv.Dimension('Car occupants'), 'Count', color="red")
bars
```

And receive same bar chart above, with error

```
WARNING:param.Bars01705: Setting non-parameter attribute color=red using a mechanism intended only for parameters
```

I would like to know how to plot bar chart in red, in Plotly (similar to Bokeh example above).